# 0 height body in HTML within WebView on Kitkat

Tags: android, html, webview, xamarin, android-4.4-kitkat

I am completely lost as to why this HTML is not working within a WebView on Android within Xamarin.  It's been a hair pulling experience trying to get something this simple working.

The HTML source is as below.  I would expect the screen to go blue, but it stays orange:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyTitle</title>
    <style>
        body {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: orange;
        }

        .fullScreenDiv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myId' class='fullScreenDiv'> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A few things I have looked into:

- It shows absolutely fine in Chrome.
- I am using Kitkat, with hardware acceleration turned off.
- "http://www.google.com/" loads fine in the WebView.
- I have attached a remote debugger (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) and it looks like the calculated height of the body is 0px, which I assume is why it is not showing.

[image: Elements]

Below is the code containing the WebView init.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}

webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(this.Context);

webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

webView.SetWebViewClient(new Client(this));
webView.SetWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());

webView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);

webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;

webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/View.html");

var x = webView.IsHardwareAccelerated; // returns false
```

Any ideas or pointers please?

Comment: Show the layout file containing the `WebView`

Comment: Squonk, I just modified the question to clarify the fact that it is using Xamarin.  I will attempt to extract the important parts of the code and add them in.

Comment: Added.  Please let me know if there's any other info that would be useful.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about Xamarin. I was expecting you to have a standard XML layout file for your `Activity` content. If Xamarin doesn't use those then I can't give any help.

Comment: I will try to reproduce in a standard XML layout.  May at least narrow down the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

We ( WizRocket) faced similar issue recently & solved it. The details are here
http://blog.wizrocket.com/2015/03/05/androids-webview-is-broken/

Comment: this link is dead. Can you post the solution here?